# What is more expensive a join or a filter in Pig?

Tags: join, apache-pig

When given the choice to either join or filter in Pig, which is more performance-intensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joins are always costly as you have to scan through second table for each tuple in table one. Consider below example

```
A = LOAD 'data1' AS (a1:int,a2:int,a3:int);

DUMP A;
(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
(8,3,4)
(4,3,3)
(7,2,5)
(8,4,3)

B = LOAD 'data2' AS (b1:int,b2:int);

DUMP B;
(2,4)
(8,9)
(1,3)
(2,7)
(2,9)
(4,6)
(4,9)


X = JOIN A BY a1, B BY b1;

DUMP X;
(1,2,3,1,3)
(4,2,1,4,6)
(4,3,3,4,6)
(4,2,1,4,9)
(4,3,3,4,9)
(8,3,4,8,9)
(8,4,3,8,9)
```

When we join in X we traverse through each tuple in B for each tuple in A. For filter we just traverse once through dataset and perform filter operation on each tuple.

```
X = FILTER A BY a3 == 3;

DUMP X;
(1,2,3)
(4,3,3)
(8,4,3)
```